# Avoiding bullet sign getting from ValidationSummary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

These are the parts of my written code

in controller

```
else if (result != null && result.LoginMsg == "Incorrectusername")
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("UserID", "Invalid Username");
    return View("Index", oModel);
}
else if (result != null && result.LoginMsg == "Incorrectpassword")
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("UserID", "Invalid Password");
    return View("Index", oModel);
}
else
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("UserID", "Invalid Username/Password");
    return View("Index", oModel);
}
```

In View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "User Name", @autofocus = "autofocus" })
        @*<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>*@
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Password" })
        @*<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>*@
    </div>
    <div>
        <b style="color: red">
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
        </b>
    </div>
```

When I enter incorrect username and pass 
i get something like

•The UserName field is required.
•The Password field is required.

What I really want is 
instead of validation summary showing bulleted points of the username and password requirments I would like a combined message if both are occuring and get rid of the bullets happening ( I know validation summary return unordered listed of items)

Comment: use CSS to remove the bullets then

Comment: Do not return a message specifically stating what the error was - you just giving hackers extra information  - just return a generic - _Invalid Username/Password_